# (GCM - MISMATCH SENDER ID) when using multiple push services

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I use Parse to push notifications. I'm using another service to push notifications as well (Layer - a chat service/SDK).

So, as long as Parse is alone (without implementing Layer) everything is fine, and I receive the notifications. Once I implement Layer, I start facing the "GCM - MISMATCH SENDER ID" from Parse. though, I can receive the push notifications from Layer.

I came across this question:[Parse.com push notifications not consistently working receiving "GCM -MISMATCH SENDER ID" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661395/parse-com-push-notifications-not-consistently-working-receiving-gcm-mismatch-s)

but it's not an option to get rid of the other SDK (Layer).

and of course I added the meta-data

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
           android:value="id:YOUR_SENDER_ID" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. It's general, not just for Layer

https://support.layer.com/hc/en-us/articles/204496844-How-can-I-use-Layer-with-other-push-services-

Answer (score 0):

You should add all of **gcm_sender_id's** to be able to provide your app with more than one push services. Take a look at the below:

> If you want to register your app with multiple additional sender IDs,
>   then the android:value in the `<meta-data>` element above should hold a
>   comma-delimited list of sender IDs, as in the following snippet:
>
> ```
> <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
>            android:value="id:YOUR_SENDER_ID_1,YOUR_SENDER_ID_2,YOUR_SENDER_ID_3"/>;
> ```

You can read more [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications-setting-up-push).